# c# using SqlClient ordering results with ORDER BY is extremely slow

Tags: c#, performance, sqlclient, sql-order-by

Following strange situation i got yesterday in c# when using SqlClient to get a sorted resultset.

Following SQL-Query for example:

`SELECT Num, Name FROM Customer WHERE Num LIKE '%V%' OR Name LIKE '%V%' ORDER BY Num ASC`

The resultset to order in this special case is about 100 lines long.

The problem is the following: If I run the query on the sql-server itself it is damn fast! The result is shown almost in the moment i click "Run query". But when I run the query in C# using SqlClient it's incredibly slow (about 5-10 seconds). I benchmarked every little part of my program and found out that the connect to the sql-server is made in about 10 milliseconds, so the link between the two machines cannot be the problem.

I tried almost everything until I found out, that the query in C# using SqlClient returns the results almost as fast as running the query directly on the sql-server, if I remove the ORDER BY Num ASC from the query.

So my question is: What the hell is SqlClient in C# doing with ORDER BY to multiply the used time by thousands of millions compared to the sql-server itself? =)

Comment: Can you post the simplest example of the C# in use demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Have you tried limiting the size of your resultset using something like RowNumber()?

Comment: This is not specifically related to SqlClient, but is a database access optimization strategy.

Comment: @Felice Pollano: From the information in the question it sounds like you are misusing the word "optimization". ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try running the query twice after one another, and see if you get a time difference. That will determine if it's the connection or the query that takes time.

When you measure how long time the connection takes, you are only measuring part of what you think. The actual session with the database isn't started until you need it, i.e. when you run the first query.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at good description over here on the same topic:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/aa4537ed-fb69-441d-82d3-0216f497f995

This query might help you spot differences between SSMS and your app.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_connections;
```

Have a look @ this as well http://forums.asp.net/t/917652.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for stealing your time, I found  the problem on my own. I used different databases (the fast and optimized production database when testing the query on the sql-server itself and the slow nonoptimized development db in c#). -.-